# With "inputType" set to "textFilter", android still reserves screen space for suggestions?

Tags: android, android-edittext

developing an android app here using API 7.  I have an EditText that we use to filter down the list beneath it, so we set the inputType to textFilter so Android wouldn't suggest words or auto-complete.

However, when the user types a character they see the popup box in which they're doing the search shrink.  It is clearly getting smaller to make room for the suggestion bar, even though the suggestion bar doesn't actually show.

Using textNoSuggestions instead appears to have the same result.  Here is the snippet for the input box:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/search_edit"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:inputType="textFilter"
    android:background="@null"/>
```

Has anyone experienced and overcome this behavior?  It doesn't repro on SenseUI, but probably because SenseUI floats the suggestion bar instead of claiming screen real estate for it.

Answer (score 3):

Try textNoSuggestions. I'm not sure what textFilter does, I was hoping to use it to limit input to 0-9 and A-F for a hex keyboard, but found this instead.

Answer (score 2):

The only thing that works consistently in my experience is textVisiblePassword. This both prevents autocorrection and doesn't change the size of the field. Very annoying.

Comment: But also prevent swipe actions on certain keyboards, such as the samsung default on the SIII

Comment: Swype is a niche entry methodology, maybe you like it, but it isn't universal. I think I pointed out that textVisiblePassword gets the desired layout with caveats like autocorrect being turned off. The post is about how to get it to universally eliminate the screen space for suggestions and I pointed out one way.

Comment: And I merely pointed out a flaw with it. I'm not talking about the specific Swype keyboard, but rather the swiping gestures on the default galaxy SIII keyboard... Which is likely the most common entry method for users on the SIII. If you don't want to support the most popular android device, that's fine, but there's certainly no harm in letting everyone know these issues. 

As such, I'd recommend this solution should never be used... I don't know about you but I'd tend to uninstall any app with such obvious failures.

Comment: Well, it completely depends... First, S3 is a popular device for Samsung, but doesn't represent the greater installed base of Android which is hovering around 50% still on Gingerbread. So as an Android developer I target what users own, not what they would like to own. I actually find the greatest issue with Android to be the fact that you can either take a broad approach, write custom controls, or be vendor specific. We haven't had the resources to be vendor specific so we tend to go with the broad approach. I uninstall apps that crash and don't work if there is a better alternative.